# SQL OR CONDITION ON TWO DIFFERENT COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two fields (@EmployeeId,@SSOId) out of which one value can come or both can come, but when i am applying OR condition it is not giving me correct output. What i am doing wrong ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_GetDetails] ( 
@UserId INT = NULL 
,@ADSId NVARCHAR(32) = NULL 
,@EmployeeId NVARCHAR(32) = NULL 
,@SSOId NVARCHAR(32) = NULL 
,@UserName NVARCHAR(100) = NULL 
) 
AS 

*/ 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
BEGIN 
SELECT [USER_ID] AS UserId 
,[FIRST_NM] AS FirstName 
,[LST_NM] AS LastName 
,[FULL_NM] AS FullName 
,[ADS_USER_ID] AS ADSId 
,[SEG_ID] AS SegmentId 
,[PHONE_NO] AS PhoneNo 
,[FAX_NO] AS FaxNo 
,[EMP_ID] AS EmployeeId 
,[EMAIL_AD_TX] AS Email 
,[SSO_ID] AS SSOId 
,[SFDC_IN] AS IsSFDC 
,[USER_SFDC_ID] AS UserSFDCId 
,[MGR_SFDC_ID] AS ManagerSFDCId 
,[ACT_IN] AS IsActive 
,[SYS_USER_IN] AS IsSystemUser 
,[PORFOLIO_OWN_IN] AS CanHavePortfolio 
,[MGR_ID] AS ManagerId 
,[LST_LOG_IN_TS] AS LastLoginDate 
,[EMP_BAND_TX] AS Band 
,[CREAT_TS] AS CreatedDate 
,[CREAT_BY_USER_ID] AS CreatedBy 
,[LST_UPDT_TS] AS UpdatedDate 
,[LST_UPDT_BY_USER_ID] AS UpdatedBy 
FROM [dbo].[USER] WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ([EMP_ID] = ISNULL(@EmployeeId, [EMP_ID])OR [SSO_ID] = ISNULL(@SSOId, [SSO_ID]) 
AND [ADS_USER_ID] = ISNULL(@ADSId, [ADS_USER_ID]) 
AND [USER_ID] = ISNULL(@UserId, [USER_ID])
AND [FULL_NM] LIKE CASE 
WHEN @UserName IS NOT NULL 
THEN '%' + @UserName + '%' 
ELSE [FULL_NM] 
END 
END
```

Comment: Are both those variables the same type?

Comment: I suggest you break this down to a small case the fails with data.  Parens don't match.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the parentheses are balanced correctly.  In any case, I would write this without the `ISNULL()`:

```
WHERE ((@EmployeeId IS NULL OR EMP_ID = @EmployeeId) OR
       (@SSOId IS NULL OR SSO_ID = @SSOId)
      ) AND
      (@ADSId IS NULL OR ADS_USER_ID = @ADSId) AND 
      (@UserId IS NULL OR USER_ID = @UserId) AND 
      (@UserName IS NULL OR FULL_NM LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%')
```

I am guessing that the `OR` is for the first two conditions.  This is where the parens don't seem to line up in the query in the question.

I prefer this construct for two reasons.  First, it handles `NULL` values *in the column values* as well as the parameter values.  And second -- because it is more general -- it is one of the standard two ways I use to handle optional parameters (the other is to use dynamic SQL which can make use of indexes).

Comment: Not working...when i exec stored procedure it give all the rows instead of one... EXEC [usp_User_GetDetails] @EmployeeId = '8123154'

Answer (score 0):

Query seems to be okay .Are you passing DBNull from you C# code or empty text

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (@EmployeeId IS NULL OR (EMP_ID = @EmployeeId)) 
AND   (@SSOId IS NULL OR (SSO_ID = @SSOId))
AND [ADS_USER_ID] = ISNULL(@ADSId, [ADS_USER_ID]) 
AND [USER_ID] = ISNULL(@UserId, [USER_ID])  
AND [FULL_NM] LIKE CASE 
WHEN @UserName IS NOT NULL 
THEN '%' + @UserName + '%' 
ELSE [FULL_NM]
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this script

WHERE EMP_ID = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@EmployeeId,0) > 0 THEN @EmployeeId ELSE EMP_ID END AND SSO_ID = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@SSOId,0) > 0 THEN @SSOId ELSE SSO_ID END